# Simple Android app with multiple layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to build a simple Android app using Android Studio. The app has a main layout and ten or more sub layouts. The user will move to one of the sub layouts by simply pressing a button. The user will move back to the main layout by pressing the back button. Each sub layout is a standalone layout with no relation or dependency on the main layout or the other sub layouts.

I have read multiple tutorials and looked at many examples. I am trying to understand what Android components I should use to build this simple app and its sub layouts.

I first tried making each sub layout be an activity, and I used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DistPerVol.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

to switch from the main layout to one of the sub layouts. However, because each sub layout is a separate activity, when the app was installed, it had multiple icons on the app screen.

I next tried using just one activity and switching to the sub layouts using

```
setContentView(R.layout.dist_per_vol);
```

to switch from the main layout to one of the sub layouts. However, this caused the back button to leave the app instead of backing up to the main layout.

Today, I read about NavigationDrawer, ActionBar, and fragments. I don't want to continue trying different components. I want a main layout that allows a user to choose a sub layout, and the back button returns to the main layout, but without multiple activities. What Android components should I use to implement that?

Perhaps multiple activities is the right way to go, but I have built my AndroidManifest.xml incorrectly. Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.byui.cit360.calculators">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Calculators">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ComparePrices">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Tip">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DistPerVol">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please share your Manifest.xml (I'm curious about the multiple app icons on the home screen, this should not happen)

Comment: Multiple icons on the screen-  you put an intent filter for the launcher in ever activity.  It should only be in your main activity.

Comment: `What Android components should I use to implement that?` Fragments.

Comment: Answer is simple , "Fragments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Gabe Sechan pointed out: just one `Activity` should have the intent filter. Then there will be just one launcher icon on the home screen, and the first `Activity` in your app which the user will see is the `Activity` with the intent filter.

It's possible to write an app with multiple `Activity`s and not a single `Fragment`. (In fact, everybody did so before Android 3.0.) These apps can also have features like an ActionBar or a NavigationDrawer.

One may dislike `Fragment`s at first because they seem complicated. But using them also offers benefits. For example an app with just one `Activity` and several `Fragment`s could use the same Navigation Drawer (the setup could happen in the `Activity`)

Answer (score 1):

Fragments is the perfect class for that.

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an
>   Activity.
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

You can put your button in the activity in order to manage which fragment to show thanks to FragmentManager.

http://sapandiwakar.in/replacing-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

You Should use ListView for this type of implementation,make the listview as main layout(or main activity) and attach a OnclickListener on every list element and by this whenever you click on any list element you will go to a new activity.
[you can see the implementation of listview here on this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)